# Linq2db AssociationAttribute implementation returns an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, associations

I have been trying to get related data by using Linq2db LoadWith extension method. My purpose is getting a user's posts by using LoadWith  extension method.

It returns an error that says like this.

**LinqToDB.Linq.LinqException: 'Expression 'Param_0.CreatedBy' is not a Field.'** but Post entity class has a property that is called CreatedBy.

[image]

Here is my AppUser class.

```
 public class AppUser : BaseEntity, IAppUser
{
    [Required, Identity]
    [Key]
    public new int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("UserDetail")]
    public int DetailId { get; set; }

    [LinqToDBAssociation.Association(ThisKey = nameof(DetailId), OtherKey = nameof(AppUserDetail.Id), CanBeNull = true, Relationship = Relationship.OneToOne)]
    public virtual AppUserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
    public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
    public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }

    [LinqToDBAssociation.Association(ThisKey = nameof(Id), OtherKey = nameof(Post.CreatedBy), CanBeNull = true)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<Post> UserPosts { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Post class.

```
 public class Post : BaseEntity
{
    public Post()
    {
        PostImages = new HashSet<PostImage>();
        PostComments = new HashSet<PostComment>();
        PostVideos = new HashSet<PostVideo>();
    }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int? PostType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PostComment> PostComments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostImage> PostImages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostVideo> PostVideos { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my BaseEntity class.

```
    public class BaseEntity : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedUser")]  //By using CreatedUser integration, an owner of post,postComment,postLike that has been created, can be found easily thanks to it.
    public virtual int? CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ModifiedUser")]  //ModifiedUser can be used in AdminUI.
    public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public int? StatusId { get; set; } //This can be Enumerations.

    public BaseEntity()
    {
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public virtual AppUser CreatedUser { get; set; }
    public virtual AppUser ModifiedUser { get; set; }
}
```

This LoadWith extension method returns that error.

```
 var appUser = _appUserRepository.Table.LoadWith(p => p.UserPosts).FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName);
```

If you would like to see the project, you can check here;

https://github.com/dogaanismail/DevPlatform

How can I handle it ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you need to add `[LinqToDB.Mapping.Column]` attribute to your properties or set `[Table(IsColumnAttributeRequired = false)]` for whole entity.

I encountered the same exception and found a solution at this [issue](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/2735) in the library repository.